# Want a Animation

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5, flash-builder4.5

My project is based on Adobe AIR/Actionscript Project and it's a small desktop application. I opened a popup using `PopupManager` Class. So here is code.

```
var _dataviewPopup = new dataviewPopup();
/*  PopUpManager.addPopUp(_dataviewPopup , FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as DisplayObject, true);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(_dataviewPopup);
```

and I remove popup using

```
PopupManager.removePopUp(_dataviewPopup);
```

So I want to give some animation to this popup when it appears and disappears, is it possible?
Is there any library available for it?

Comment: When you say animation, do you mean the you'd like to animate the window itself?  As in expand open, and collapse closed?

Comment: yes MR.Sandy Gifford, i want some effect when window expand or collapse...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this tutorial to see how you can use the NativeWindow class to animate new windows.
Hope it helps
http://blog.flashdesign-store.com/?p=128